# Is there a creature in mythology that is a frost bird or a frost phoenix?

Tags: mythical-creatures, myth-identification

I searched a lot but I couldn't find a creature that is similar to a frost phoenix or a frost bird, or a giant creature similar to a frost bird for example.

It's for a project (I like to keep real mythology in my story) and I want something as close as this as possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### The [Pomola](http://www.native-languages.org/pomola.htm) is  a snow bird spirit in Native American mythology, it lived on [Mt Katahdin](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/TjWikiKatahdin.jpg) and caused cold weather

> In Penobscot folklore, the Pomola was a bird spirit that lived on Mt Katahdin. It was associated with night, wind, snow, and storms. Apparently it had a moose's head according to some legends. The [Penobscots](http://www.penobscotnation.org/) and [Abenakis](http://www.tolatsga.org/aben.html) avoided climbing to the top of this mountain so as not to disturb it.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

In Greek mythology, the giant Alcyoneus had seven daughters: Phthonia, Anthe, Methone, Alcippe, Pallene, Drimo, and Asteria.

When their father was slain by Heracles, they threw themselves into the sea, and were changed into **ice-birds**.

To be more [specific](http://www.theoi.com/Nymphe/NymphaiAlkyonides.html), the species they transformed into was the kingfisher.

---

<sub>source: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0104:entry=alcyonides-bio-1&highlight=</sub>